# Protect wordpress custom page with login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am new to wordpress, and I have just started working on a custom page template, and just can't get the content on the page not to be visible without first logging in. So I've started with copying the basic template:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Full width with no title template
*/
get_header();
?>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</header> <!-- / END HOME SECTION  -->
<?php zerif_after_header_trigger(); ?>
<div id="content" class="site-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-left-wrap col-md-12">
            <div id="primary" class="content-area">
                <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
                    <?php 
                        while ( have_posts() ) : 
                            the_post();
                            get_template_part( 'content', 'page-no-title' ); 
                            /* If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template */
                            if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
                                comments_template();
                            endif;
                        endwhile;
                    ?>
                </main><!-- #main -->
            </div><!-- #primary -->
        </div><!-- .content-left-wrap -->
    </div><!-- .container -->
</div><!-- .site-content -->
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Now when I open the page I get prompted to enter login details(I'm using digimember plugin). However, now I want add my custom content on the page, so I added some HTML markup after php logic inside the main element:

```
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
                    <?php 
                        while ( have_posts() ) : 
                            the_post();
                            get_template_part( 'content', 'page-no-title' ); 
                            /* If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template */
                            if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
                                comments_template();
                            endif;
                        endwhile;
                    ?>
                 <h1>Should not be visible but it is</h1>
                </main><!-- #main -->
```

Now I still see the login form, but I also see the string 'Should not be visible but it is'. How can I restrict this content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this condition for visitor and longed In user.

```
<?php
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      echo 'Your Code here !!!';
   } else {
      wp_login_form( $args );
   }
?>
```

For more details you can visit this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/).

Comment: yeah, but I want to use default login form that comes with digimember..as I said this form comes up without any code, I'm not sure I can include it hardcoded in the else clause

Comment: <?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    wp_login_form( $args );
}
?>

Comment: Visit this url "http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/08/30/adding-a-login-form-to-a-page" this is help full for you.

Comment: Husain I really appreciate your help. We're almost there. With this code, I do really see login form and it works great. The only issue is, this login form that I see is not the one provided by digimember plugin, I think it is just default wordpress login form. And as I said, the one that I want actually shows on other pages without any coding. If I could get the other login form to show, would be great. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution. All I had to was to just use the shortcode for the login form.